# Using a for loop to populate a dictionary

Tags: python, for-loop, dictionary

I'm having some trouble generating the dictionary I've named "appInfo" using the code below. When it is run like this, only the last application number entered gets saved in the appInfo dictionary. It seems like it should be pretty easy, but I haven't been able to find a fix. I'm using Python 3.5.2.

```
appDict={'AA':{'appType':'app name one','fileLoc':'C:\\app1.docx'},
     'BB':{'appType':'app name two','fileLoc':'C:\\app2.docx'},
     'CC':{'appType':'app name three','baseDoc':'C:\\app3.docx'},
     'DD':{'appType':'app name four','baseDoc':'C:\\app4.docx'},
     'EE':{'appType':'app name five','baseDoc':'C:\\app5.docx'},
     'FF':{'appType':'app name six','baseDoc':'C:\\app6.docx'}}
appInfo=dict()
appNumList=[]
while True:
    print('Enter an application number (XX-00-00). Press Enter to stop:')
    appNum=str(input())
    if appNum=='':
        break
    appNumList=appNumList+[appNum]
    appShow='/'.join(appNumList)
    appNumLength=len(appNumList)
    appNumSep=re.compile(r'[A-Z]+')
    mo=appNumSep.findall(appNum)
for num in appDict.keys():
    if num in mo:
        appInfo[num]=appDict[num]
print(appInfo)
```

Comment: "mo=appNumSep.findall(appNum)"  you reset value every iteration.

Comment: Side-note: In general, and particularly if this is Python 2, you rarely want to use the `keys` method of `dict`s. `dict`s are already iterables of their keys, so `for num in appDict:` gets the same results (and avoids making a temporary `list` that contains a shallow copy of the `keys` in Python 2; in Python 3 it only avoids creating a simple wrapper object). Of course, since you want the value too, you should really iterate the items: `for num, val in appDict.items():` (`.viewitems()` in Py2 to avoid copy) `if num in mo: appInfo[num] = val`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your array **mo** gets overwritten through each iteration of the while loop. When you loop through appDict.keys() **mo** only contains the most recent input. I think you meant to append to **mo** like this:

```
appDict={'AA':{'appType':'app name one','fileLoc':'C:\\app1.docx'},
     'BB':{'appType':'app name two','fileLoc':'C:\\app2.docx'},
     'CC':{'appType':'app name three','baseDoc':'C:\\app3.docx'},
     'DD':{'appType':'app name four','baseDoc':'C:\\app4.docx'},
     'EE':{'appType':'app name five','baseDoc':'C:\\app5.docx'},
     'FF':{'appType':'app name six','baseDoc':'C:\\app6.docx'}}
appInfo=dict()
appNumList=[]
mo=[]

while True:
    print('Enter an application number (XX-00-00). Press Enter to stop:')
    appNum=str(input())
    if appNum=='':
        break
    appNumList=appNumList+[appNum]
    appShow='/'.join(appNumList)
    appNumLength=len(appNumList)
    appNumSep=re.compile(r'[A-Z]+')
    mo.append(''.join(appNumSep.findall(appNum))

for num in appDict.keys():
    if num in mo:
        appInfo[num]=appDict[num]

print(appInfo)
```

Comment: That is an interesting catch. My mo array is operating properly now, but appInfo is completely empty. Thanks for finding that problem in my problem-filled code!

Comment: I changed the append() line. I was appending an array returned by findall() without joining it into a single string. The edited code should work.